# Repeat executed code after user input

Tags: java, loops, methods

I'm creating a program that will calculate he cost of traveling. Each segment has a cost, and user is asked to enter the cost for each segment, then enter 3 segment ID's (0-6). The cost of the 3 ID's is added to give a final price.

I need to repeat the program from the beginning if user enters >=1 (see comment at the end), how can I do this? Also, could I improve my program, and how?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentArrays{
    public static void main(String[] args){


      Scanner seg0 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner seg1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner seg2 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner seg3 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner seg4 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner seg5 = new Scanner(System.in);

      int[] data = new int [6];
      data[0] = 0;
      data[1] = 0;
      data[2] = 0;
      data[3] = 0;
      data[4] = 0;
      data[5] = 0;

      /* Segment values */

        while(data[0] == 0){

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 0:");
            data[0] = seg0.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 1:");
            data[1] = seg1.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 2::");
            data[2] = seg2.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 3:");
            data[3] = seg3.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 4:");
            data[4] = seg4.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter cost for segment 5:");
            data[5] = seg5.nextInt();

           /* Path inputs */

           Scanner node1 = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner node2 = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner node3 = new Scanner(System.in);

           int node1value;
           int node2value;
           int node3value;
           int pathCost;

           System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 0 of path:");
              node1value = node1.nextInt();

           System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 1 of path:");
              node2value = node2.nextInt();

           System.out.println("Enter ID of segment 2 of path:");
              node3value = node3.nextInt();

          /* Path cost calculation */

          pathCost = data[node1value] + data[node2value] + data[node3value];
              System.out.println("The cost of the trip is: $" + pathCost);

          /* Repeate or end program */

           Scanner end = new Scanner(System.in);

           int userChoice;

           System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or any other number to evaluate another path:");
              userChoice = end.nextInt();

           if (userChoice == 0){
              System.out.println("The program has ended");
              break;
              }
              else if(userChoice >= 1){
              /* REPEATE ALL OF THE ABOVE HERE */
              }
          }

     }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why are there ***6*** scanners? 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: 6 Scanners? 1 is more than enough. Also if you want to repeat the whole program on `1` as input. just enclose the relevant part of code that you want repeated inside a while loop that loops if `userChoice` is 1

Comment: I think I understand. What about the scanners? How am I supposed to do it instead?

Comment: @Kronos, just initialize one and keep using the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably make the class more object oriented.  However, you could simplify what you have by breaking up your code using methods:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentArrays{

static int[] data = new int [6];

public static void getSegmentIDs() {
   ...
}

pubilc static int getUserMenuChoice() {
   ...
}

public static void main(String[] args){

 int exit = false;

 while(!exit) {
   getSegmentIDs();
   choice = getUserMenuChoice();
   if (choice == 0) exit = true;
 } 

}
}
```

Comment: I have divided the program into 3 methods, getIDs(); , pathCalc(); and the main method. Now I have a problem as the DATA variable is in getIDs(); and I require it in pathCalc. "Cannot find Symbol"

Comment: you could make it a static member of the AssignmentArrays class.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, that works now, however my program begins at pathCalc(); rather than getIDs();. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the whole thing into a do while statement by doing this:

```
  String answer ="";
  do {
  Scanner seg0 = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner seg1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner seg2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  YOUR CODE CONTINOUS

  /* Repeate or end program */
  System.out.println("would you like to redo? (Y/N)");
  answer = end.next();
  } while(answer.toLowerCase().contains("y"));
```